In VSC, Platformio keeps initializing
Out of the blue (at least for me) I can't run PlatformIO anymore.
VSC keeps initializing PlatformIO core. I have uninstalled it, reinstalled it, but always the same result, keeps initializing. It happens with a fresh project or with a project which i have been worling on for weeks.
Your advice is much appreciated.
I run OSX Sonoma 14.4.1
VSC as follows:
Version: 1.88.1 (Universal)
Commit: e170252f762678dec6ca2cc69aba1570769a5d39
Date: 2024-04-10T17:42:52.765Z
Electron: 28.2.8
ElectronBuildId: 27744544
Chromium: 120.0.6099.291
Node.js: 18.18.2
V8: 12.0.267.19-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 23.4.0
Platformio: Version 3.3.3

I reinstalled Platformio, and i iven reinstalled VSC

Please read this question: Should questions that are resolved by reinstalling some software be closed as unreproducible?, and then ask yourself if your have provided enough info for anyone to help you .... (there seems to be enough info that is missing from this question, to start with version info).

Luuk, I added the version info as indicated for VSC as well as Platformio. I'm not an expert, more a user and quite happy until yesterday. I hope someone reads the updated info and poiunts me in the right direction. Regards, Erik
